# Primefaces: Editable object in accordionPanel with Dynamic = True

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, accordion

I am trying to achieve functionality where I am generating the tabs in according panel dynamically according to the list.

List is of say some object e.g Person

Now attribute corresponding to each person, I am showing in each tab in a form.
Values are loaded correctly but when I edit those value I am not getting updated values at the backing bean, I am getting only old values.

Can somebody please explain why ?

Here is the code.

**Person Object**

```
public class Person {

    String name;

    //getter setter

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**Backing Bean**

```
@ManagedBean(name = "editor")
public class EditorBean {

    private List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        persons.add(new Person("dhruv"));
        persons.add(new Person("tarun"));
    }

    public void testAction() {
        System.out.println(persons);
    }

    // Getter Setter*****************//
    public List<Person> getPersons() {
        return persons;
    }

    public void setPersons(List<Person> persons) {
        this.persons = persons;
    }
}
```

XHTML Code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h1>Hello World PrimeFaces</h1>

    <h:form>
        <p:accordionPanel value="#{editor.persons}" var="person" dynamic="true">

            <p:tab title="#{person}">
                <p:inputText value="#{person.name}"></p:inputText>
            </p:tab>

        </p:accordionPanel>

        <p:commandButton action="#{editor.testAction()}" value="testAction"></p:commandButton>
    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

When I run the same with with dynamic="false". This works fine. But in my real scenario I have lots of data which I cannot afford to paint in one go thats why I want to use dynamic = true.

Can somebody explain how to achieve this if not by dynamic = true ??

Comment: What is the scope of `editor`?

Comment: I have tried both the scope view and session... I am getting the same resuld in both of these scopes

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're having stale values in your accordion is that dynamic accordions default to `cache="true"`. This attribute causes the accordion to not reload new/updated values. To cause an ajax refresh on tab open, set `cache="false"` on your accordion

Comment: the problem is not loading of the value... the problem is binding the value to the backing bean in case I have some form inside the accordian panel tabs with dynamic = true .. can you help me out with this ?? Try to replicate the above example to get better understanding.

Comment: @dhroove, you can't have a form both inside and outside the accordion (i.e. nested `<h:form/>`). That's illegal html. That or you're not explaining your issue clearly

Comment: @kolossus.. oh my bad I have written form.. but its not form I wanted to specify.. as u can see I have take one text field in example. When I load value from my list to text field, values are getting loaded properly.. but after editing those values.. and submitting the form.. I am not getting that edited value in the backing bean...

Comment: @dhroove The usual reason why model values are not updated is either a conversion or validation error. Both of them may occur silently. Check your browser's developer console to confirm a) The request is being sent when you click on the button b)The server is not responding with a `Validation Error: Value not valid` in the http response payload